# Multiple queries in different methods Twitter4j Processing

Tags: java, twitter, processing, twitter4j

I am trying to execute separate queries in different methods, the code below is not my actual code but is just an example of the error, i have

`Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();`

called in both methods, however i get the error

> IllegalStateException: Cannot use this builder any longer, build() has already been called

if i make it global then i get the same error, 
this will probably be just me being stupid but i cant work it out, iv been staring at it for too long now.

here is my code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

  double lat = 51.5171;
  double lon = 0.1062;
  double res = 37;
  String resUnit = "mi";

public void setup(){

cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

  queryLon();
  queryBir();
}

void queryLon(){
try {
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

  Query query = new Query();
  query.setRpp(100);

  QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query().geoCode(new GeoLocation(lat,lon), res, resUnit));
  ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();


  for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {

  Tweet t = (Tweet) tweets.get(i);
//User u= twitter.showUser("twitter");

String location = t.getLocation();
println("Location: " + location);

  }
}
}

catch (TwitterException te) {
println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
};

}

void queryBir(){
try {

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

  Query query = new Query();
  query.setRpp(100);

  QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query().geoCode(new GeoLocation(lat,lon), res, resUnit));
  ArrayList tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();


  for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {

  Tweet t = (Tweet) tweets.get(i);

String location = t.getLocation();
println("Location: " + location);



  }
}
}

catch (TwitterException te) {
println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
};

}
```

any help would be appreciated, cheers.

forgot to mention im using Twitter4j and Processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty clear: the error tells us that `build()` can only be called once, and you're clearly trying to call it multiple times. So, simple solution: when you want to make a new TwitterFactory, either capture the result of `cb.build()` in a variable the first time you call it, and then reuse that, or create a new instance of `ConfigurationBuilder` and call its build() everty time you create a new `TwitterFactory`, although that seems pretty wasteful. Try to capture your `cb.build()` first.

Comment: cheers man, thanks for pointing that out, i should have worked that out but the combination of sleep deprivation and too much caffeine has hindered my ability to think straight.